# Filevault login screen slow to start after trying to install Windows using bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp

Since trying to install Windows 7 on my iMac with Lion 10.7.4, using Boot Camp, I noticed that the login screen where it asks for the FileVault password is taking a lot of seconds to be displayed.

When I turn on the computer, after the sound only a blank screen is shown for a lot for seconds.

Even after removing the Windows partition using Boot Camp, this slow down persists.

Anyone with similar problem, or solution?

Answer (score 1):

The common cause is when the OS X EFI isn't selected in [startup preferences](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3571) (and then stored in NVRAM) so the system needs to read all drives before defaulting to the lowest numbered Mac volume.

A more oddball case would be if the kernel caches are somehow invalid and must be recreated which [slows a boot sequence](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/booting/booting.html) considerably.